# Combining solutions to a PDE, then truncating that summed solution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Given a PDE
\begin{cases}
u_{t} - 3u_{xx} =0 \qquad &\text{in}\ \ 1_{T} := (0,1) \times (0,T], \\
u(x,0) = 5\sin(2\pi x) - 30\sin(3\pi x) \qquad & \text{on} \ \ (0,1),\\
u(0,t) = 0 \quad ,u(1,t) = 0 \qquad &\text{on} \ \ (0,T]
\end{cases}

Let the solution be
$$ u(x,t) = Be^{-3n^2 \pi^2 t} \sin(n \pi x),$$ for $B$ any constant and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

> Argue why for every $N\in \mathbb{N}$
> $$ u(x,t) := \sum_{n=-N}^{N}B_{n}e^{-3n^2 \pi^2 t} \sin(n \pi x)\tag{1}$$
> is also a solution to the PDE, for $B_{n}$ any constant. Then argue why in general we can simply this expression to just
> $$ u(x,t) := \sum_{n=0}^{N}B_{n}e^{-3n^2 \pi^2 t} \sin(n \pi x).\tag{2}$$

#### Attempt at solution

For $(1)$ : By lemma, if $\{u_{n}\}$ is a sequence of solutions to the boundary value problem, then their linear combination is a solution as well. The solution
$ u(x,t) = Be^{-3n^2 \pi^2 t} \sin(n \pi x)$ suggests there exists an infinite number of solutions since $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ , thus $(1)$ is a solution to the given PDE.

---

For $(2)$ : Since the solution $(1)$ is in fact the trivial solution (all terms cancel out such that $u(x,t) =0 \ \forall N$), we may obtain a distinct general solution by truncating the sum from $n=0 \to N$.